# Get JSON substring from log message

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I have log messages like this

> message:2019-06-07 15:49:10.110 INFO 5632 --- [http-nio-9026-exec-1] 
>      *****************.jdbc.audit.AuditHandler : AUDITHANDLER:{"USER":"0c27e6ef- 
>      b615-4328-91d6- 
>      a94d1f5d799a","OBJECT":"VersionController","METHOD":"version","ARGUMENTS": 
>      [""],"ACTION":"GET","RESULT":"SUCCESS","DURATION":"15"} 
>      logmessage:AUDITHANDLER:{"USER":"0c27e6ef-b615-4328-91d6- 
>      a94d1f5d799a","OBJECT":"VersionController","METHOD":"version","ARGUMENTS": 
>      [""],"ACTION":"GET","RESULT":"SUCCESS","DURATION":"15"} class:AuditHandler 
>       host:******2 type:java level:INFO @timestamp:Jun 7, 2019 @ 15:49:10.110 
>       pid:5632 @version:1 path:D:/idea/*****/elk-example.log timestamp:2019-06- 
>       07 15:49:10.110 thread:http-nio-9026-exec-1 _id:c4OOMWsBphFrSEBogeCE 
>       _type:_doc _index:logstash _score: -

I need to take a `JSON` string, coming from `AUDITHANDLER` (uppercase) and use `JSON` fields to filter log messages

Comment: You can try to make a grok filter in logstash with some regex and that will give you the required json.

Comment: If you want tot use a grok filter, this one should work: `AUDITHANDLER:%{GREEDYDATA:json_string} class:AuditHandler`